# How could Marco's dad use "Yahoo! Maps" two years before it was launched?

Tags: animorphs

[#45 The Revelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Revelation_(novel)) was published in 2000. On page 21 of that book:

> Where would "they" be waiting? His computer screen was still up — no
>   screen-saver. At the bottom was a minimized "window," the words
>   Yahoo! Maps written inside. I grabbed the mouse and clicked. Bingo—
>   1366 Fairmont and a road map in case I planned to drive. I didn't.

However, according to [Yahoo! themselves](https://web.archive.org/web/20080713214826/http://yhoo.client.shareholder.com/press/timeline.cfm) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Maps), "Yahoo! Maps" was only launched in 2002.

[image]

How could Marco's dad use "Yahoo! Maps" in 2000?

And more interestingly, how could K.A. Applegate (or actually, probably ghostwriter  Ellen Geroux) write about "Yahoo! Maps" in 2000?

Comment: She guessed? It's not an illogical extension of their services.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18265/4918 How could Dudley have wrecked his PlayStation if the PlayStation didn't exist yet? [harry-potter]

Comment: @b_jonas Haha, nice one. Only here, the error was mine, no the authors'. (I also like the idea that Vernon had signed up for product testing, lol.)

Comment: @Fiksdal I'd say the error belongs with Yahoo!; note that Wikipedia uses your first link as its main source, and it doesn't mention the older Maps.  Wikipedia's second source kind-of mentions that something did previously exist, but states it in a way that sounds like the previous service wasn't called "Yahoo! Maps"

Comment: Cf. this bold prediction also made in 2000:  https://img.buzzfeed.com/buzzfeed-static/static/2016-03/23/19/enhanced/webdr07/enhanced-14191-1458774784-1.jpg

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You've misunderstood the "New" in their timeline.  The New Yahoo! Maps was released in 2002, but the first Yahoo! Maps existed at least as far back as February 1998.  [Its homepage exists on Archive.org's Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/19980208001912/http://maps.yahoo.com/).

Comment: IIRC, Y! maps went from being a Yahoo-branded MapQuest to a Yahoo-branded Here, except Y! bought Here and AOL owned MapQuest?

Comment: @KutuluMike The second source on Wikipedia does mention dropping MapQuest, but inspecting the source of the archived page results in nothing obvious; maybe it was entirely back-end, in which case regular users wouldn't have known?

Comment: Probably not. IIRC, Yahoo! rebranded other people's services as their own, including MapQuest and Google search, but it "looked like" Yahoo! services. Then in the early 2000s they started buying up vendors and/or writing their stuff in-house instead.